# Combobox items issue - blank items

Tags: c#, combobox, datasource

I couldn't find any answer for following issue with two depended comboboxes in Windows Forms project, Visual Studio 2010, .NET4, Windows 7 x64.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<string> items1 = new List<string>() { "", "1 Item", "3 Items", "5 Items" };
            comboBox1.DataSource = items1;
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> items2 = new List<string>();
            switch (comboBox1.Text)
            {
                case "": 
                    break;
                case "1 Item":
                    items2.AddRange(new string[] { "I1" });
                    break;
                case "3 Items":
                    items2.AddRange(new string[] { "I1", "I2", "I3" });
                    break;
                case "5 Items":
                    items2.AddRange(new string[] { "I1", "I2", "I3", "I4", "I5" });
                    break;
            }
            comboBox2.DataSource = items2;
        }
    }
}
```

When expand combobox2, there is initially one "blank item".
But when I select "5 items" in combobox1 and then blank item again, in combobox2 there are 5 blank items visible.
Same with "3 items" - combobox2 holds space for 3 blank items.

I've tried with different data sources (array, BindingList, BindingSource) and additional methods (Items.Clear, set DataSource to null, clear DataBindings etc.) but with no success. The only workaround I've found is to bind a list with one empty element.

Does anyone know better way to "clear" that blank items away?

Comment: have you tried using a BindingList instead of a List?

Comment: @ProgrammingDude yes, I've tried. The same behavior.

Comment: @mj82, what you think about disable combobox?

Comment: @progpow Yeah... I've just start thinking about this ;) Just curious if someone will find solution for this "bug" - or "feature"....